# Compare lines ignoring certain characters with difflib

Tags: python, difflib

I have an `input.txt` and an `output.txt`. The output file is just `Line1\r\n`; the input file is just `Line1\n` (written the way you'd expect, I just can't display windows/unix newlines here).

I am struggling to get [`difflib.ndiff`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) to report that the files are identical.

I know I can tell it to ignore certain characters via the `charjunk` argument. By default, it's set to ignore whitespace and tabs via `difflib.IS_CHARACTER_JUNK(ch)`.

I looked at the source code for [`IS_CHARACTER_JUNK()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.IS_CHARACTER_JUNK):

```py
def IS_CHARACTER_JUNK(ch, ws=" \t"):
    return ch in ws
```

I made my own version, and set ndiff to use it, in `a.py`:

```py
from difflib import ndiff

def windows_newlines_charjunk(ch):
    return ch in "\r"

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    input = f.readlines()
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    output = f.readlines()

diff = ndiff(input, output, charjunk=windows_newlines_charjunk)
print("".join(list(diff)))
```

When I run `python2 a.py`, I get:

```sh
- Line1
+ Line1
?      +
```

which is code for [ndiff saw a difference between these two lines and is trying to draw your attention to the difference. If the difference is whitespace, this will appear very confusing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ).

How can I make `ndiff` understand that windows vs unix newlines is not a difference?

Comment: The answer to this is recorded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588672), i.e., that `charjunk` or `linejunk` are used only aesthetically, not for diffing purposes, and [many](https://bugs.python.org/issue14332) [people](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/578883-using-difflib-compare-text-ignoring-whitespace-differences) were [similarly](https://grokbase.com/p/python/python-list/09489r4w4x/how-to-ignore-white-space-changes-using-difflib) confused